# What regions does TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId support?

Tags: c#, timezone, iana

I am trying to get all Iana time zones on a .net8 application. I can't use any open-source packages, so I am stuck with pulling DotNetIds out of the Windows registry. Right now, I am iterating through all TwoLetterIsoRegionNames over all DotNetIds to (try to) gather all IanaIds. I am not sure that it gets all IanaIds as the list is only 332 long, and according to the tzdb, the list is 352 cannonical zones and 597 total IanaIds. Is there a way to get all of these time zones this way or am I going to have to use TimeZoneConverter.

For example, I am only getting Indianapolis for Indiana, but there should be much more

```
                    var systemTimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones(); 
                    var isoRegions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                        .Where(c => !c.IsNeutralCulture && c.LCID != 0x7f)
                        .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.Name))
                        .GroupBy(r => r.TwoLetterISORegionName)
                        .Select(g => g.First())
                        .ToList();
                    
                    var timeZones = new List<TimeZone>();
                    foreach(var systemTimeZone in systemTimeZones)
                    {   
                        //Try to get all iana ids
                        var ianaIds = new HashSet<string>();
                        foreach(var isoRegion in isoRegions)
                        {
                            string ianaId;
                            if (!TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId(systemTimeZone.Id, isoRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName, out ianaId))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            ianaIds.Add(ianaId);
                        }

                        foreach (var ianaId in ianaIds)
                        {
                            if(!TimeZoneInfo.TryFindSystemTimeZoneById(ianaId, out ianaTimeZone))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            Adds time zone to list.
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I'm curious about your "no open source" restriction. Is it license concerns (no copy left, for example) or code provenance concerns. With an appropriate license and thorough code review, you can often overcome the open source hesitancy (particularly with something as restricted in scope as IANA codes)

Comment: True, I may need to go that route, but we'll see

Comment: .NET itself is open source, and some parts use third-party open source components developed outside of Microsoft.  You'll find the same with just about every other language and platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId` method uses data from ICU that ultimately comes from the [`windowsZones.xml`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) file in CLDR.  The purpose of that data is to provide a Windows time zone that *approximates* one or more IANA time zones, thus allowing conversion between the two.

However, that file alone doesn't represent *all* IANA time zones.  To do that, .NET would also have to take into account various aliases and administrative zones that are present in the [`timezone.xml`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/bcp47/timezone.xml) file.  It only does that for `TryConvertIanaIdToWindowsId`, so that alias are handled correctly in the reverse mapping.

So, while your question about which supported regions are available can be answered by looking at the `territory` field in `windowsZones.xml`, that won't help your goal of getting a list of all IANA time zones.

To get a list of all IANA time zones, on Linux or MacOS, you can just use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`.  On Windows, there isn't a function built-in to .NET that can return this.  However, you can use `TZConvert.KnownIanaTimeZoneNames` from my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) library on any platform.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I've been reading up a ton on time zones and have seen much of your work lol. Thanks again for the guidance!